# cerbero build system: how to rebuild?

Tags: build-process, gstreamer

Building OpenWebRTC from sources and it uses the cerbero build system. OS Ubuntu.

Built once. Then changed a file in the OpenWebRTC sources: `$HOME/cerbero/sources/linux_x86_64/openwebrtc-0.3.0/local/owr_video_renderer.c`. Then:

```
./cerbero-uninstalled -c config/linux.cbc package -f openwebrtc
```

Why it's saying that "openwebrtc -> already built"? How to rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

You should use git to create a local branch in the project (openwebrtc folder)

```
$git checkout -b <name_local_branch>
```

Then in recipes/ look for the openwebrtc.recipe (or similar) and look for these lines and modify them just to look like this

```
remotes = {'<name_local_branch>','file:///path/to/source'}
commit = '<name_local_branch>/<commit>'
```

I am also working on this and it works for me once, hope it helps you. If you get to make it working, tell me. Check this link fyi http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Building-GStreamer-SDK-from-latest-sources-for-ARM-Android-td4670784.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach and it didnt work. However if you are ok to mess with your local repository, below works:

In the file .recipe:

remotes = {'origin': '/local/directory/where/you/git/cloned'}

followed by: cerbero -c buildone